# Creating a new column with 0 and 1 values based on regex result

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has values:

```
data_df

0         student
1         sample text
2         student
3         no students
4         sample texting
5         random sample
```

I use regex to extract rows with word 'student' and my result is as below:

```
regexdf
0         student
2         student
```

I aim to create a new column in the main dataframe with 0 and 1 values. i.e. row 0 should be 1, row 5 should have zero.(As the 'regexdf' has 'student' in row 0 and 2) How do I match the indexes in both and create a column?

Answer (score 2):

Using regex:

```
data_df = data_df.assign(regexdf = data_df[1].str.extract(r'(student)\b', expand=False))
data_df['student'] = data_df['regexdf'].notnull().mul(1)
print(data_df)
```

Output:

```
                 1  regexdf  student
0         student  student        1
1     sample text      NaN        0
2         student  student        1
3     no students      NaN        0
4  sample texting      NaN        0
5   random sample      NaN        0
```

### Edit

```
df_out = data_df.join(regexdf, rsuffix='regex')

df_out['pattern'] = df_out['1regex'].notnull().mul(1)

df_out['Count_Pattern'] = df_out['pattern'].cumsum()

print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
                1   1regex  pattern  Count_Pattern
0         student  student        1              1
1     sample text      NaN        0              1
2         student  student        1              2
3     no students      NaN        0              2
4  sample texting      NaN        0              2
5   random sample      NaN        0              2
```

Comment: I would want to retain regex result in a separate variable 'regexdf' and later append to main dataframe as 0's and 1's as posted in question

Comment: I use a function for regex: So here I cannot use data_df = data_df.assign `def regex(series, regex):
    series = series.str.extract(regex)
    series1 = series.dropna()
    return (series1)`


`regexdf = regex(comp_df,(r'.*(?<!no )(student ?in|student ?out).*(hallway|library)))`

Comment: Can this be simply done by matching row indexes? regex index (0,2) are the results. So the resulting new column appended to the new dataframe will have 1 in row 0 and 2, in other rows '0'

Comment: @sagar.. I am a bit confused.  now it appears you simply want to join data_df and regexdf on index.  `data_df.join(regexdf, how='outer')` or `data_df.merge(regexdf, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Comment: But the resulting new column should have 0 and 1 based on whether the row had the regex pattern or not which will not happen in the above join code

Comment: Ultimately I have to count the number of rows which have the pattern. But I want to have the resulting rows which match the regex as 0's and 1's appended to a single main dataframe.

Comment: @sagar if this solution helped you would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
df['bool'] = df[1].eq('student').astype(int)
```

or

```
df['bool'] = df[1].str.match(r'(student)\b').astype(int)

                1  bool
0         student     1
1     sample text     0
2         student     1
3     no students     0
4  sample texting     0
5   random sample     0
```

If you want a new dataframe then

```
ndf = df[df[1].eq('student')].copy()
```

Comment: I would want to retain regex result in a separate variable 'regexdf' and later append to main dataframe as 0's and 1's as posted in question